# Angular 2 - Nested Routing

Tags: angular, routes

I am beginner in angular 2 and i am trying to do some routing practice. I have a button on productDetailComponent. Now when i click on the button, it want the page to route to moreDetailComponent.

```
export const TutorialRoutes: Routes =[
i w
  {
    path: 'Company',

    component: CompanyComponent,
    children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'people'},
      {path: 'price', component: PriceComponent},

        {path: 'products', component: ProductComponent,

        children:[

            {path: '', redirectTo:'product-details'},
            {path:'product-details', component:ProductDetailsComponent},
            {path:'more',component: MoreDetailsComponent}

        ]

        },


    ]

  }
];
```

// button to move to page (moreDetailsComponent)

```
<button routerLink="more">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

A guess (because the question isn't quite clear to me)

```
<button routerLink="../more">Add</button>
```

Comment: the url change to from /details to /more but the page did not change.

Comment: The route should be `Company/products/product-details` and change to `Company/products/more` if the button is in the `ProductDetailsComponent`. If the button is somewhere else, it's not supposed to work.

Comment: Yeah the button is in the ProductDetailsComponent. When i click on the button, the url changes alright but the page remains does not navigate to the moreDetailsComponent

Comment: Do you get any error in the browser console? Are you using the express server or some other?

Comment: There is no error in my console.. I am using my inbuilt server.

Comment: What is "my inbuilt server"?

Comment: Try using to add `useHash: true` to `RouterModule.forRoute(useHash: true)` and see if it works this way. The URL will look different. I'm not sure about this though, because for this to help, you would have had an error message.

Comment: well.. I am lost now and confused already.. May be i should go and read more and try to get this done.

Comment: It's hard for me to diagnose without more details.

Comment: Uhmm. May be i should reframe the question very well